# DOT NET LinkButton rendering differently in app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback

In my MasterPage.master page, I have defined `LinkButton` :

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="drawer-item drawer-logoff" ID="LinkButton8"
    ClientIDMode="Static" ForeColor="#333333" runat="server"
    OnClick="LogoOutLinkButton_Click">
    <div class='drawer-item-img'>
        <img src='/Visual/Images/log_out.svg' />
    </div>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Which, on most parts of app, renders **correctly** as:

```
<a id="LinkButton8" class="drawer-item drawer-logoff"
    href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$LinkButton8','')" 
    style="color:#333333;">
    <div class="drawer-item-img">
        <img src="/Visual/Images/log_out.svg">
    </div>
</a>
```

but, on *some parts* of app, which I can't seem to corretly identify, button renders as:

```
<a id="LinkButton8" class="drawer-item drawer-logoff"
    href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
        WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$LinkButton8", "", true, "", "", false, true))' 
    style="color:#333333;">
    <div class="drawer-item-img">
        <img src="/Visual/Images/log_out.svg">
    </div>
</a>
```

How can I identify the problem and fix it? If my question is not clear enough, please write a comment and I'll try to improve it.

**EDIT**
The problem is created by one of my `ascx` user controls. I'll try to post minimal, complete, and verifiable example in a while.

Comment: as far as I can tell the only difference is the content of the `href` tag, right? It looks like auto generated code right there. What is the problem? Does it not work?

Comment: correct, ``DoPostBack`` is changed to ``DoPostBackWithOptions``. And ``DoPostBackWithOptions`` do not work as intended, not even ``LogoOutLinkButton_Click`` is called.

Comment: I assume your "some parts" implies that you've used your button in multiple places. since the HTML is not the same I assume your markup is not always exactly identical. can you update your question and add the markup for the parts where it doesn't work?

Comment: I used "some parts" because I'm not sure where exactly it doesn't work, I managed to find only one page so far. I'll try to update question with somehow minified markup in a minute.

Comment: What is actually *wrong*? You said "not even LogoOutLinkButton_Click is called." What does that mean? Is a postback happening, and your event handler isn't actually called, or is a postback not happening at all? If the latter, it's probably because there is a failed validator.

Comment: @aquinas thank you, those are great questions. Postback is not happening at all. Not even ``Page_Load`` gets called, no matter if I click the button or try to run generated js from console

Comment: So, it is almost certainly the case that there is a validation error on the page. It's also almost certainly the case that you don't want validation for a log out button. Try adding `CausesValidation="false"` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @aquinas thank you, this hack fixed my issue. I'm not sure yet if it's not too ugly to keep there, but you certainly made my day.

Comment: @Kajbo, it's not a hack at all. `CausesValidation=false` is exactly the correct solution to use. That's what it's there for. Don't take my word for it. Here's the source code for the LoginStatus control used in ASP.NET: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/loginstatus.cs,261

Comment: @aquinas ok then, thank you again. You can repost your last comment as answer and I'll accept it as solution if you want.